# Retrieve data from webservice, with side effects - what method to use

Tags: rest, http

I am in the process of writing a webservice that sends data to the client, but it has side effects.

This webservice will be called periodically, and any data that is being sent to the client will be marked as such and will not be sent again.

The client is 100% stateless, I can't expect it to send something like a timestamp of the last request. The administration of state lies with the web service.

I am a firm believer that GET requests must be idempotent, so I cannot use that as the method. POST and PUT on the other hand are used to create/update resources, which is not the case here.

What http method would you choose and why?

Comment: I’d probably just go with POST. If the client can not be expected to implement basic HTTP measures such as a conditional GET with an If-Modified-Since or sth. like that ... then the other end is probably not the one to be puristic about HTTP either.

Comment: I would use PATCH - this is neither a pure read, nor a create nor full update. It is a partial update in the sense that client indirectly sets the "OK, i've seen this" marker on the resource. PATCH is also not idempotent.

Comment: In addition to what @CBroe already said, the semantics of a POST content are totaly up to the service maintainer. POST is not just a simple `CREATE resource` operation but more like an all-purpose tool for anything that can't be described by other HTTP operations well enough. What are the side-effects you're talking about? If they relate to logging (or similar stuff) depending on your design they may be acceptable as they don't influence resource states.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your answer, it is insightful. If you put it in an answer, I'll make sure to accept it. Thanks all!

Comment: Hm, that’s a bit short for an answer ... Maybe write up an answer yourself? Then you can take into account the other comments, too (valid points as well), and let us know what you decided to go with in the end. I think that would be preferable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went with `POST`.

Mostly the argument

> If the client can not be expected to implement basic HTTP measures such as a conditional GET with an If-Modified-Since or sth. like that ... then the other end is probably not the one to be puristic about HTTP either.

is what persuaded me.